# how to external image link images download for opencart products

Tags: php, opencart

Thanks for advance,

1. I have installed the theme then I have installed import/export
   Module for products.
2. I have Made the CSV file according existing CSV file which I have
   export through the Module. ( I have made that csv file fields
   accordingly).

But there are one problem with "image_name" fields i am trying to get images form extranal server like (https://me-cdn.xyz.com/pub/media/catalog/product/V/1/V1_KHNB01649961_C2N1.jpg).

When i am importing the file all fields are stored but images not stored it's showing Opencart default image.

Please help me how will work my csv file along with images.

Comment: the field on the db will only look for the image filename in the default folder, it doesn't do the upload of the image. you're supossed to ftp upload all the images and then upload the product catalog (with the filename of the image in that folder). I guess you could edit all those references in the db to absolute path images, but i'm not really into opencart

Answer (score 0):

You are only saving image name in table actually you are not uploading image on server. opencart have a function for image resize and rending you can find function in bellow file.

```
catalog/model/tool/image.php
```

Function name is `public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {`

if you want your show your save image path then you can change this file through vqmod or ocmod.

For testing purpose add this line you above function

```
public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {
       $pos = strpos($filename, 'https://me-cdn.xyz.com/pub/media/');

       if ($pos !== false) {
           return $filename;
       }
```